# Unable to access VisualSVN Server repositories after computer hard drive crashed

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

My hard drive crashed and I have all the files but had to install the operating system. After I did that and installed Visual SVN Server, I imported my old repositories into it.I can create new repositories fine, but when I try to import an existing repository and then commit changes I hadn't committed before the crash, using right click on the project in the file system (with Tortoise installed) I get various error messages. One of them says

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL.. access to /svn/xxx/trunk forbidden
```

When I look at the users on the security tab of the project folder, the permissions are the same. On the Subversion tab, is shows  the number of revisions, the last revision, etc. But when I click to show the log, it prompts me to go off line, then I get errors. I also get prompted for a login, which had never happened before. I looked at the htpasswd file in the repositories location on the old repository and the new one and the files are exact. I just need to get these project back under SVN and not lose their history of changes. Visual SVN Server site says I can create a dump file on the old server to import, but I just have all the files from backup of my previous hard drive.

Can someone point me to any more information about how to do this?

Comment: I think, you can write to VSVN support https://www.visualsvn.com/support/

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2015? Please, upvote and accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to bahrep's suggestion to look in the event viewer, I am able to fix the problem. I will have to research the "why", but I did find that the repositories I couldn't  access had conf/VisualSVN.lck and the ones I could access had conf/VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini. So I deleted the .lck file and added the VisualSVN-SynAuthz.ini file and I am now able to access those repositories.
Thanks for your help.
Judy

Comment: This issue happened because you installed newer VisualSVN Server version than the one you had installed originally. You had to install the same VisualSVN Server version first and upgrade it later. See the note in my answer.

Comment: Just adding this to complete the answer. The other hard drive on my computer went out and I had more security problems with SVN. I found out that in Visual SVN Server, the problem repositories needed to have an entry for Everyone under manage security menu for the repository.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check what's logged to [VisualSVN Server event log](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/),
2. Make sure that you have the same settings configured in **VisualSVN Server Manager | Action | Properties** as were on the crashed server. You should verify whether you have Windows or Subversion authentication and authorization enabled. It should be the same as on the old server.

**IMPORTANT:** On the new machine you should install the same VisualSVN Server version as was installed on the old machine! If you had VisualSVN Server 2.5 or older installed, [download and install latest VisualSVN Server 2.5 version](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/2.5/).

Comment: Duh, I never thought of the event logs. I do see some errors so I will research. I did go back to the computer I used before this one where I still had the repository files, but had deleted the server program so I reinstalled it there and had some similar problems. So on my current computer, I installed an older version of Visual SVN Server and I am able to  get Tortoise to work on some of my folders but not on others. I haven't found the reason for that yet, but it does give me hope.

Comment: @user359409 the log should reveal the root cause. What's logged when you get those errors? Specify the log event and the error you get on client (in your question).